# PHP : Data which is of one digit is not deleted, but two digit data gets deleted

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 PHP pages to delete employee data from table. For that, user inserts employee id, and press delete, to delete data from table.

Now, problem is, whenever I inserts id of one digit(2,3,8 etc), id is not deleted. However, if two digit id is inserted (12,19,99 etc), it gets deleted.
Please help me to solve where I am wrong.

Here is my code for first PHP page:

```
<form action="deleteemp.php" method="post" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')">
  Enter id to delete data<input type="text" name="EmpId" required> 
  <button type="submit" >Delete</button>
</form>
```

Here is my action PHP page,

```
<?php

$EmpId = $_POST['EmpId'];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$connection) {
    die("Connection failed " . mysql_error());
}
$db_conn = mysql_select_db("hms", $connection);
if (!$db_conn) {
    die("Connection failed " . mysql_error());
}
$query = "DELETE FROM employee_details WHERE emp_id = " . $EmpId;
$db_result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if ($db_result) {
    echo "Data Deleted Successfully !";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='homepage.php'>Back to homepage</a>";
} else {
    echo "Data Not there. Try Again !<br>";
    echo "<a href='deleteemp1.php'>Search again</a>";
}
```

Comment: Done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's being received by PHP? And `var_dump($query)` to see what you're sending to the DB?

Comment: No, I had not done it yet. Let me check it.

Comment: var_dump($_POST) shows me value passed (2 in my case).

var_dump($query) shows NULL

Comment: you have to `var_dump($query)` after the line where you define it. if you get your message "data not there", do `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: EVEN echo mysql_error(); SHOWS NOTHING. I WILL NOW TRY TO DROP AND RECREATE MY TABLE. 
I will be using Int(10) for emp_id. Will it again create any problem?

Comment: and what about `echo $query;` (after the line `$query = ...`) ? it's a "simple code", so the explanation should be simple. Are you sure to query the correct dbname ?

Comment: I didnt got your point. Yes, I am sure I am querying right DB name.

Answer (score 2):

`echo "data not here"` is incorrect. `mysql_query` returns boolean false on FAILURE. An empty result (no matching IDs) is **NOT** a failure. It's a successful query which happens to have an empty result set.

Your code should be more like

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_affected_rows($result) == 0) { 
   die("No rows deleted");
}
```

And note that you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and using an obsolete/deprecated DB library.

Comment: Main problem is, for one digit ids, it is showing ID NOT FOUND, even if ID exist inside table.

Comment: are you sure that id's there? e.g. if you're using varchar fields (for some reason), and it's stored as `id='1[space]'`, then `where id=1` will never match it.

Comment: I am using INT for id.

Comment: then try changing your query into a select and see if `where id=$single_digit_value` brings up anything. there's nothing wrong with your code (other than the sql problems and mis-interpreting return values), so there's not much we can do. you'll have to dig into this since we don't have any access to your system/data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = "DELETE FROM employee_details WHERE emp_id = '$EmpId'";
$db_result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

if ($db_result)
 {
    echo "Data Deleted Successfully !";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='homepage.php'>Back to homepage</a>";
} 
else
 {
    echo "Data Not there. Try Again !<br>";
    echo "<a href='deleteemp1.php'>Search again</a>";
}
```

Comment: surely $empid is an integer !?!

Comment: you just echo $EmpId  after getting $EmpId= $_POST['EmpId'];

Answer (score 0):

This seems some exceptional issue, so try [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) before passing value to SQL query.
Try using this for assigning value to $EmpId:

```
$EmpId = (int) $_POST['EmpId'];
```

Comment: Nope. Same problem.

I actually rebuit my table. But, problem is still there.

Comment: Then please try changing data type(i.e. to varchar) of column in mysql itself. It will make us sure if issue is with INT type only or not.

Comment: Tried it. No difference. I really dont know whats the problem my DB has with 1 digit number!

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change below code from

`$query = "DELETE FROM employee_details WHERE emp_id = " . $EmpId;`

TO

`$query = "DELETE FROM employee_details WHERE emp_id =".$EmpId;`

Just try. This might work for you